# Swift: Add cells containing a custom label from an array to an UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

How do I programmatically add cells to a `UITableview` and fill the cells with data from myArray[cellNumber]. The data in the array is of type String. The tableview is just an `UITableView` connected with an outlet.

All the examples I've found is either +30 lines or doesn't work... I'm using swift 4 and `UIKit`.

Comment: can't you find about gazillion examples and sample codes around the net in this topic?

Comment: I've tried, some is 20 lines of code, which I think Is to much, other doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you Handle cell selection.

```
    // Data model: These strings will be the data for the table view cells
    let myArray: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]

    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                  // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
                  var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
                // set the text from the data model
                cell.textLabel?.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row]
           return cell
     }
```

Things you should consider for :

- Conform to the TableView Delegate and DataSource protocols.
  `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`
- Connect the Interface Builder Outlets
  Connect the referencing, dataSource and delegate outlets.
- Register the cell class
  In the `viewDidLoad` method call the `registerClass(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`.
- Create the cell with correct ReuseIdentifier name `var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCel`

By now your ViewController class should look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet
    var tableView: UITableView
    var myArray: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.myArray.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
}
```

The example below is an adaptation and simplification of a [longer post](https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) from We ❤ Swift.

Apple Developers Doc [Create a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

```
    let array = ["Monday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, I need more info from your code to check another possible error.

In case you create the tableview from code, you need to define

> tableview.datasource = self
>
> tableview.delegate = self

and make class extend from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: I get this error at the class definiton line "Type '[Name of the class]' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'" 
and this error "Method does not override any method from its superclass" at the line "override func tableView..."

Comment: Ok, for the first error, yo need to extend the class with UITableViewDataSource, and inside, call 3 functions: numberOfSections, where normaly put return 1, numberOfRowsInSection, where you return the [collection name}.count, where collection is the array where you have the information and the cellForRowAt that is the func wich I explain in my Answer (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

the below example should work for you. Enjoy :)

```
class TableviewDemoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

//MARK: - IBOutlet
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//MARK: - Variables
let arrayToPopulate = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
let tableviewCellHeight = 50.0

//MARK: - View initializer
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupTableview()
}

func setupTableview() {

    tableView.datasource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

//MARK: -UITableViewDelegate
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayToPopulate.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayToPopulate[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableviewCellHeight
} }
```